# User Interface for Javascript and/or php

Tags: user-interface

What are some of the better known well established user interface libraries? For Java I found Vaadin to be very nice. Is there something out there for javascript and php?

A few good ideas and comment to point me in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears react is new on the scene and building momentum. Probably asked this question too soon.

Would appreciate what you guy can tell me on top of react and what is out there for PHP.